# How to query for events that are "now" when event times are stored in different timezones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, mongoid

Specifically:  I have a Schedule model where a person cans schedule one event per day at the same time every day. Like this:

```
class Schedule

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 

  field :hour,      :type => Integer, :default => 8
  field :ampm,      :type => String,  :default => "am"
  field :time_zone, :type => String,  :default => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

  field :monday,    :type => Boolean, :default => true
  field :wednesday, :type => Boolean, :default => true
  field :friday,    :type => Boolean, :default => true

  field :tuesday,   :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :thursday,  :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :saturday,  :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :sunday,    :type => Boolean, :default => false

  embedded_in :user

end
```

I have a rake task that is run hourly and I just want to query for all schedules that require and event "now".   So for example if it is noon UTC on a Monday, then a schedule with :timezone => EST and :hour => 7 should be in the results as should a schedule with :timezone => PST and :hour => 4.   This of course is a lot more tricky when it is, say, 1am UTC Tuesday because that is Monday in both PST/EST.

I thought about just normalizing the hour so everyone was on utc but this would create a mess for me with the days because someone might schedule something for 11pm wed which is actually thurs utc, so "normalization" would become a total pita where the days users select in their scheduler form wouldn't correspond with the days we stored in the db.

I'm using mongoid in case anyone has a mongoid specific solution.

Comment: "EST" isn't a time zone. It's *part* of a time zone - the standard time part of Pacific time. Sounds like you want to convert each event's local time to UTC, and compare that with the current UTC time.

Comment: I realize, I'm abbreviating.  I'm hoping there is a way to avoid converting.

Comment: It's important *not* to abbreviate in this sort of thing. EST has a specific meaning, and it's not the meaning you want. You could potentially convert the other way - work out the current day/time in each of the time zone's your interested in, but you're going to have to have a conversion of *some* kind. Also, be aware of local times that occur twice or are skipped due to DST transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not an option to save the dates in UTC, you'll have to query each time zone separately. Something like:

```
wdays = [:sunday, :monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday]
now = Time.now
TimeZone.all.each { |time_zone|
  remote_time = now.in_time_zone(time_zone)
  schedules = Schedules.where(
    :time_zone => time_zone.name,
    :hour => remote_time.strftime("%-l").to_i,
    :ampm => remote_time.strftime("%P"),
    wdays[remote_time.wday] => true,
  )
  # process schedules
}
```

Comment: I considered this but since there are 142 timezones I shied away from that solution.   Might ultimately be what I do though after I benchmark the real impact of that many queries once an hour.   Sounds like the basic answer to my question about the existence of some super tricky query is: no, you can't do it.

Comment: You can group the time zones by UTC-offset which makes 33 offsets. And since there are time zones with an offset of :30 and :45, you can run your script every quarter hour with 25, 0, 7 and 1 queries respectively.